# Given that we have a Coxian-2 distribution, what is P(X<0.5)?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am working on a probability question that asks me to compute the variance and the expected value given that we have a coxian 2 distribution with $\mu_1=5$, $\mu_2=6.1$ and $\alpha=0.2$.

Once this was done, it said to calculate $\mathsf P(X<0.5)$.

I was able to calculate the expected value and the variance, but I am not quite sure how to calculate $\mathsf P(X<0.5)$.   It was suggested that I give the probability density function, but I do not know how I should do this.   Any help is greatly appreciated.

I did the following calculations for the first part, and I'm fairly certain they are correct.

$\begin{align}\mathsf E[X]~=~&(1/\mu_1)+\alpha(1/\mu_2)\\[1ex]=~&(1/5)+0.2(1/6.1)\\[1ex]=~&0.23278689 \\[2ex]
\mathsf{Var}(X)~=~&\mathsf E[X^2]-\mathsf E[X]^2\\[1ex]=~&0.10386455-0.05418974\\[1ex]=~&0.04967481\end{align}$

Comment: Formatting tips [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: @probablyme thanks

Answer (score 1):

Looks good.

[WolframAlpha sais:](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=CoxianDistribution%5B%7B0.2%7D,+%7B5,+6.1%7D%5D)

> $$\boxed{\begin{array}{c}\textsf{CoxianDistribution[\{0.2\},\{5,6.1\}]}
> \\\begin{array}{|l:l|}
> \hline\textsf{mean }& 0.232787
> \\\hdashline\textsf{standard deviation }& 0.222878
> \\\hdashline\textsf{variance } & 0.0496748
> \\\hdashline\textsf{skewness } & 1.83354
> \\\hdashline\textsf{kurtosis } & 7.92726
> \\\hdashline\textsf{CDF } & \mathsf P (X\leq x) \approx \begin{cases} 0.909091 e^{-6.1 x}-1.90909 e^{-5 x}+1 & : x\geq 0\\
> 0 & :\textsf{(otherwise)}\end{cases}
> \\\hline\end{array}\end{array}}$$

http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CoxianDistribution.html